# Solidity Docs Code Example divide by two then require multiply quotient by two

Tags: solidity

The below is right from the solidity readTheDocs page.  Its from the Safe Remote Purchase section on https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#micropayment-channel.

function Purchase() payable {
         seller = msg.sender;
        value = msg.value / 2;
        require((2 * value) == msg.value);
    }

What are the last two lines doing? Dividing the value by two and then requiring that the inverse must be equal to the original number.  What's the point? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solidity only allows for integer arithmetic. So if you have an odd number and divide it by 2, it will truncate the decimal. Re-multiplying by 2 at that point would not give you back the same number. So the require statement essentially verifies that the number of wei sent is an even number.

Comment: ok, so it's no wonder it doesn't make sense in the context of this contract.  It didn't mention anywhere that only even payments are accepted.